# POSTMAN: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

Tags: postman, web-api-testing, postman-testcase

I am working on chaining of the API requests via POSTMAN. I was trying to get a value of a variable from response body to use it into other API requests under my collection but I am getting an error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')" while running attached API request.
Could you please guide on why this is not working? I am using POSTMAN version v9.24.1.
Here is the response body
[image]

[image]

Comment: That should be because you don't have data field in the bodyData.x

Comment: Please show your responseBody

Comment: @ChristianBaumann Hi, The response body is updated in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you having that `x` when setting `value`?

This does what you want: `let value = bodyData.data[2].first_name;`

Comment: Thanks Christian. This works like a charm. I took the JSON path from online JSON Path finder and thought it was required. I removed x and then worked fine. Thanks again.